# How to draw Red-Black Binary Search Trees?

Tags: binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I am having trouble visualizing how these Red-Black Binary Search Trees are made. I have a book that talks about them, but I am still not entirely sure I get how they will look. Let's say I'm going to inserts letters A through K (11 values, in that order) into a tree that's empty. Is this what it would look like?

**{Bracket} is red node**

***Normal is black node***

```
                       F
           {B}                   {J}
         A      D             H      K
             {C} {E}        {G} I
```

I am open to any critiquing.

Comment: For a red black tree, it has to maintain the following condition: [*Every path from a given node to any of its descendant leaves contains the same number of black nodes.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) You can see that node H has different black heights between its left and right subtrees, so this isn't a valid red-black tree.

Comment: Thank you for your input. If that is the case, then would changing my "I" to be a red node "{I}" fix the heights?

Comment: Yes it would. Remember to count the `nil` leaves as well. Also, going up the tree from black to red increases the black height by 1, but going from red to black does not. However, whether or not this would result from insertions from A to K, I haven't worked out.